# Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, multithreading

while running the code i am facing this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.NullPointerException at 
com.example.example1.service.RecordData.run(RecordData.java:87)
```

This is my Program:

```
public class SearchParser {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "share";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "";

    try {
        List<RecordData> list = new ArrayList<RecordData>();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName,
                userName, password);

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet mysqldata = stmt
                .executeQuery("select * from product_links");
        while (mysqldata.next()) {

            RecordData data = new RecordData();
            data.setId(mysqldata.getInt("id"));
            data.setDomain_name(mysqldata.getString("domain_name"));
            data.setCommon_link_name(mysqldata
                    .getString("common_link_name"));
            data.setHead_element_pattern(mysqldata
                    .getString("head_element_pattern"));
            data.setProduct_title_pattern(mysqldata
                    .getString("product_title_pattern"));
            data.setProduct_link_pattern(mysqldata
                    .getString("product_link_pattern"));
            data.setCurrent_price_pattern(mysqldata
                    .getString("current_price_pattern"));
            data.setImage_src_pattern(mysqldata
                    .getString("image_src_pattern"));
            data.setDecscription_pattern(mysqldata
                    .getString("decscription_pattern"));
            list.add(data);
        }
        for (RecordData data : list) {
            RecordData p = new RecordData();
            p.start();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }

}
```

}

It is basically a program which fetch data from database.

```
public class RecordData extends Thread {
    int id;
    String domain_name, common_link_name, head_element_pattern, product_title_pattern, product_link_pattern, current_price_pattern, image_src_pattern,
            decscription_pattern;
    public RecordData data;

    public RecordData() {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDomain_name() {
        return domain_name;
    }

    public void setDomain_name(String domain_name) {
        this.domain_name = domain_name;
    }

    public String getCommon_link_name() {
        return common_link_name;
    }

    public void setCommon_link_name(String common_link_name) {
        this.common_link_name = common_link_name;
    }

    public String getHead_element_pattern() {
        return head_element_pattern;
    }

    public void setHead_element_pattern(String head_element_pattern) {
        this.head_element_pattern = head_element_pattern;
    }

    public String getProduct_title_pattern() {
        return product_title_pattern;
    }

    public void setProduct_title_pattern(String product_title_pattern) {
        this.product_title_pattern = product_title_pattern;
    }

    public String getProduct_link_pattern() {
        return product_link_pattern;
    }

    public void setProduct_link_pattern(String product_link_pattern) {
        this.product_link_pattern = product_link_pattern;
    }

    public String getCurrent_price_pattern() {
        return current_price_pattern;
    }

    public void setCurrent_price_pattern(String current_price_pattern) {
        this.current_price_pattern = current_price_pattern;
    }

    public String getImage_src_pattern() {
        return image_src_pattern;
    }

    public void setImage_src_pattern(String image_src_pattern) {
        this.image_src_pattern = image_src_pattern;
    }

    public String getDecscription_pattern() {
        return decscription_pattern;
    }

    public void setDecscription_pattern(String decscription_pattern) {
        this.decscription_pattern = decscription_pattern;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(data.domain_name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because this

```
public RecordData() {
    this.data = data;
}
```

does absolutely nothing. You are assigning a field to itself. Since it starts of `null`, it also ends up `null`.

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but you probably want to assign some other value to `data`.

```
public RecordData(RecordData data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

Comment: @user3013623 No, you are not. You can, by adding a `RecordData` parameter and invoking the constructor with a `RecordData` argument.

Comment: @user See my edit. Invoke the constructor with some `RecordData` argument you have in your main. You might need another constructor that doesn't have any arguments, so that you can create the objects that don't have a `data` value.

Comment: @user3013623 You're welcome. Consider accepting/upvoting answers to your questions if they helped you solve your problem.